# python closure list append vs += syntax

Tags: python, list, closures

The following code works perfectly:

```py
def f():
    a = []
    def g(x):
        a.append(x)
        print(a)
    return g

a = f()
a(0)
a(1)
```

But when I replace `a.append(x)` with `a += [x]` I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment` usually solved with a `nonlocal a` declaration inside nested function.

Why this difference of behaviour on closures?

Comment: For the same reason this error always occurs, because your assignment statement to a variable, in this case, `a` when you do `a += [x]` make is local by default, so when you try to reference it, doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Now, `a.append(x)` works because `a` is never assigned to, so it is a free variable, and it resolves to the variable in the enclosing scope. This is the same reason you can do `b = a + [x]` but not `a = a + [x]` You can think of `a += [x]` as `temp = a.__iadd__(x); a = temp; del temp`

Comment: Doesn't `+=` syntax refers to `__iadd__` method? So `+=` doesn't seem to be a real assignement...

Comment: `__iadd__` is a hook that can be called (if implemented, otherwise it falls back to `__add__` and it will try `__radd__` of the right operand if the left has neither, then it will raise a TypeError) when `a += [x]` is executed, but it *also* assigns the result of that to `a`.  So it *is* an assignment.

Comment: Just check out `dis.dis("x += 1")` and you'll see a `STORE_NAME` for `x`